# Dummy Rest API not working on phone React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using http://dummy.restapiexample.com/ API. While using POSTMAN and creating a new employee using POST, it seems to work, but when I use axios in React Native and do the same thing the POST is returning success response but when I try GET method to get all the new employees I'm not seeing the newly created employee which worked on POSTMAN.
This is my POST method:

```
create(){
    axios.post('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create',{
      "name":this.state.name,
      "salary":this.state.sal,
      "age":this.state.age
    }).then((res)=>console.log(res.data)).then(()=>this.setState({createModal:false})).catch(err=>console.log(err))
  }
```

and this is my GET method:

```
async getData(){
    await axios.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees').then((res)=>this.setState({employees:res.data.data},()=>console.log(res.data.data))).catch((err)=>console.log(err))
  }
```

Comment: can you try copying the json from your postman and replace the json your axios is using,. then let us see, if its still cant add,

Comment: Yes I tried hardcoding the values but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Did the console log worked inside GET method?

Comment: Yes it returns only the initial values, not the response that should contain the newly created user

Comment: Did the postman returns new values which you created ?

Comment: Yes it did return the new value

Comment: Create new user and get users are in the same screen or two screens ?

Comment: It's in the same screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216031/discussion-between-akila-devinda-and-ashish-mathew).

Answer (score 0):

From your example code it seems that you are making a call over http. Note that such calls are blocked by iOS and Android unless you explicitely specify a domain that is allowed to be reached over http.

More information about networking can be found here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/network

> By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL.
>   If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http)
>   you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception. If you
>   know ahead of time what domains you will need access to, it is more
>   secure to add exceptions only for those domains; if the domains are
>   not known until runtime you can disable ATS completely. Note however
>   that from January 2017, Apple's App Store review will require
>   reasonable justification for disabling ATS. See Apple's documentation
>   for more information.

Either allow the domain for non-secure request or use https.

Comment: what kind of error? More information please. Is your endpoint configured to work with https requests?

Comment: I didn't create this endpoint,it is just something I found online and also using http is giving the response the first time, but after using POST it doesn't give the updated list.

Comment: ah, ok. I didn't realize that dummy.restapiexample.com is an actual website. Yes, that website can't be reached over https. You'll have add a transport security exception https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#test-your-integration or you have to use an API that can be accessed over https.

Comment: I tried on my emulator and it seemed to work ,thank you for your help

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: on Android it is more or less the same as you need to specify android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" or to specify each individual domain you want to connect to.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem, but its working anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem had something to do with running on Android device. Once run on the emulator it seemed to work fine